# Generate time series

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive, time-series

I've two columns in a table: time, volumes.

The time columns has resolution of seconds (`format: YYMMDDHHmmss`) and volumes are traffic volumes. I want to write a script that can calculate time series consisting of total volumes over a 5 win window; time series with 5 min bins.

How can I do that? Group by?

Comment: Discrete bins for time series data will guarantee the introduction of artifacts that depend on your interval choice. Some sort of moving average is almost always preferable especially when the alternative is the creation of "data" that aren't there.

Comment: How dense is your data?  Do you have data for almost every second?  Or, do you have one data point per hour and you want to interpolate to get the numbers in the 5-minute intervals?  If the data is sparse, do you have a begin and end time for the measurement, or just a single time?  If just a single time, is it the beginning of the period, end, middle, or arbitrary?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I wasn't clear -- I wanted to know how to do this in mysql/Hive. The data is fairly dense -- every sec. One can get bins by going over the time points and modding by 300. And then calculating sum/avg of the total volume in the respective bins. However, how to do this in sql? Thanks again